# How do I alter the RenderingContext in a pipeline?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I need a pipeline to intercept the building of the sitecore `RenderingContext`, specifically I need to alter the `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource` attribute on the fly.

I need to do this because I've added a variable into my Datasource in sitecore. I was manipulating this in the controller but when I turn on the experience editor it falls over before it even hit's my controller. I'm guessing somehting higher up needs the datasource to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging about I discovered this pipeline:

```
namespace Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering
{
    public class EnterRenderingContext : RenderRenderingProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (args.Rendered)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.EnterContext(args.Rendering, args);
        }

        protected virtual void EnterContext(Rendering rendering, RenderRenderingArgs args)
        {
            IDisposable item = RenderingContext.EnterContext(rendering);
            args.Disposables.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Reflected out of `Sitecore.Mvc.dll`

---

I can now replace this pipeline with my own and change the values of the `RenderingContext` before they're built:

```
public class RedrowEnterRenderingContext : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.EnterRenderingContext
{
    private const string _developmentKeyword = "$development";

    private IDevelopmentQueryServiceV2 _coUkDevelopmentQueryService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDevelopmentQueryServiceV2>();


    protected override void EnterContext(Rendering rendering, RenderRenderingArgs args)
    {

        //Make your changes to the items that are used to build the context here
        if (args.PageContext != null &&
            args.PageContext.Item != null &&
            args.Rendering.DataSource.Contains(_developmentKeyword) &&
            args.PageContext.Item.TemplateID.Guid == TemplateIdConst.V2Development)
        {

            args.Rendering.DataSource = args.Rendering.DataSource.Replace(_developmentKeyword, 
                args.PageContext.Item.Paths.Path);
        }
        //build the context using the existing functionality
        base.EnterContext(rendering, args);
    }
}
```

I'm manipulating the datasource in a specific scenario but this code could be adapted to do many jobs.

you register this thus:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc.renderRendering>
        <processor type="Namespace.MyEnterRenderingContext, DLLName"
                   patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.EnterRenderingContext, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
      </mvc.renderRendering>
    </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

---

One issue with this is that it shows up in the `BrokenLinkValidator`. You can override this though and create your own:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyBrokenLinksValidator : BrokenLinkValidator
{
    public RedrowBrokenLinksValidator() : base()
    {

    }

    public RedrowBrokenLinksValidator(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
    {
        ValidatorResult returnVal = base.Evaluate();
        if (returnVal != ValidatorResult.Valid)
        {
            Item obj = base.GetItem();
            ItemLink[] brokenLinks = obj.Links.GetBrokenLinks(false);
            //are all the broken links basically because they are contextual?
            if (brokenLinks.All(a => a.TargetPath.Contains("$development")))
            {
                foreach (ItemLink brokenLink in brokenLinks)
                {
                    Database database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                    //try again but replacing the varible with a context
                    var secondTryPath = brokenLink.TargetPath.Replace(
                        "$development", obj.Paths.Path);

                    Item secondTryItem = database.GetItem(secondTryPath);
                    if (secondTryItem == null)
                        return returnVal;
                }

                //if we've got here then all the links are valid when adding the context
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;
            }
        }

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something similar in my blog post here: http://sitecore-estate.nl/wp/2014/08/queryable-datasource-on-sublayouts/ 
It's not MVC tho, but might be helpful to use it sometime.

Comment: I'll take a look @Younes . I wrote this as I struggled to find any documentation on the subject.